# jQuery Shapeshift plugin. Elements not fit to row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with jQuery Shapeshift plugin. I want to have blue, green and yellow blocks in a one row, but Shapeshift cant fit that. Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="klocek1"></div>
  <div class="klocek2"></div>
  <div class="klocek3"></div>
  <div class="klocek4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .ss-placeholder-child {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.klocek1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.klocek2 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.klocek3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
}

.klocek4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".container").shapeshift({
  minColumns: 1
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/odu70g2t/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should arrange mininum colums property accordingly, for example in my screen when I sett minumum colums, it fills the row properly.
As below:

```
$(".container").shapeshift({
  minColumns: 3
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I had minimum columns set and I need it for 1 for responsive. Even if 3 it still not working.